# Is it possible? GUI in c# , app in C++

Tags: c#, c++

Is it even possible to create GUI layer in C# and rest of application in C++? If I am not wrong one of antyvirus software had GUI made in Delphi. How it could be done ?

Comment: Yes, Visual studio was written in C++ with a WPF front end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options for doing it, including:

1. Use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to call into the C++ DLL from C#.
2. Expose a COM interface from the native code, and call it from C# using [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
3. Write a native Windows service and call into it from managed code.
4. Use C++/CLI to write a managed library in C++, which you can easily link to from C#.

If you're starting from scratch, option 4 is probably your best option. (Aside from just writing the whole thing in C#, that is.)  The first three options all involve some additional wrangling and overhead, and probably aren't worth the hassle if you don't have a compelling reason such as needing to interact with an existing native library or having some need for a service-oriented architecture.

Answer (score 4):

If you write your business logic in C++/CLI, and your UI in C#, it shouldn't be a problem. If you want to write in pure ANSI C++, you might have to write C++/CLI wrappers around the objects you want to expose to C#.

Answer (score 3):

write the app logic in c++ dll, then use pinvoke from c# to talk to the dll.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is very difficult to use much more than a c-style api with platform invoke. You have to deal with mangled function names and then you still have to deal with the object-oriented code differntly. A com wrapper would probably be a better bet. Of course, you can always wrap the object-oriented code into a C-style api.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987307/286801). It seems to answer your problem